# Get all the roles after include with main entity in Entity framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have three entities which are Account, Role and AccountRole. Through repository pattern I have fetched all the accounts, roles and accountRoles like below:

```
var accounts = _accountRepository.Query()
                .Include(x => x.AccountRoles)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Role);
```

Now I would like to get a single account information with all it's roles. So I have written the below query. **But the problem is only *first role* comes** out.

```
var userAccount = accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                                    .Select(x => new AccountDto
                                    {
                                        Id = x.Id,
                                        Name = x.UserFullName,
                                        FirstName = x.FirstName,
                                        LastName = x.LastName,
                                        Email = x.Email,
                                        Mobile = x.Mobile,
                                        UserName = x.UserName,
                                        PhotoUrl = x.PhotoUrl,
                                        IsActive = x.IsActive,
                                        Roles = accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new RoleDto
                                        {
                                            Title = x.AccountRoles
                                                    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                                                    .Select(x => x.Role.Title).FirstOrDefault()
                                        }).ToList()
                                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can anyone help me to write the proper query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this part

```
Roles = accounts.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new RoleDto
{
    Title = x.AccountRoles
            .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
            .Select(x => x.Role.Title).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList()
```

is quite strange mixture, you should simply use the navigation property (yes, it is not only for includes as some people think).

Second, don't apply `FirstOrDefault()` when you want to get all items rather than the first only

```
// here x variable type is Account (coming from the outer Select)
Roles = x.AccountRoles
    .Where(ar => ar.IsActive)
    .Select(ar => new RoleDto
    {
        Title = ar.Role.Title,
    }).ToList()
```